# Measuring Event Duration for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an audio application and I'd like to track for long the users are listening per track. I wasn't able to find it on the official guides.

Is it possible to collect the event duration for events like video/audio playback on Firebase similar to Flurry Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to develop this as a custom event. The playback time is stored in the client side until an event that would pause the playback occurs. When this happens, the client-side automatically sends the latest duration information to Firebase.